# How to reload a single section in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

Hey I'm having trouble trying to figure this one out. UITableView has a method [tableView reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *) withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)] now according to the Apple docs this method takes in an NSIndexSet object and reloads what ever section specified by the index set. The problem is even though im only sending in one section to this method it ends up reloading all the sections and i can't understand why this is happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: maybe you mistake the NSIndexSet?

Comment: [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:animation]; thats the exact line. When the user clicks a row it should call to reload the section of the row the user clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you try reloading only a section, you must also provide the populating process section by section:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DetailViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

   if (indexPath.section == 0){
      //blablabla
      cell.textLabel = blabla
   }
   else if (indexPath.section == 1){
      ///blablabla
      cell.textLabel = blabla2
   }
return cell;
}
```

... because reloading the table (is it only a section or the whole table) wil call the method above

Comment: Hmm i see what u r saying now. What i need to do is here at my other question maybe you can help. [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525402/adding-a-view-underneath-a-row-in-uitableviews[/link]

Comment: well, if I answered to your current question, you better accept it, before I start following your next link